# How to refer to an existing DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I do a check if a div is DataTable

```
 if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable($("#Table"))) {
            $("#Table").DataTable().clear();
            $("#Table").DataTable().rows.add(data).draw();
        }
```

If it is true, how can I refer to it as a object so that I do not need to use jquery selector anymore.

A use of

```
var Table=$("#Table").DataTable();
```

would instead create a new DataTable even if the old one is there already

Comment: You'd have to use something like `var Table=$("#Table").DataTable();` when you first create the DataTable, then you can refer to it using that variable anytime afterwards.

Comment: Is there no other way? For example in another function or web worker callback that I need the table?

Comment: There's this, as in the answer below: https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables() . It will get you all tables on the page, as an array, or an API instance that lets you access all of them. If you've got multiple tables though, you would still need to know which one you want to target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [**`$.fn.dataTable.tables()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.tables()). Here is an example to retrieve the instance (API) of a table on the page and clear it :

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var table = $.fn.dataTable.tables( { api: true } );
  table.clear().draw();
}, 1000)
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/fp6ev0vc/**

Comment: It might be a bit off topic, but in your opinion, do you think manipulate table via this selector would be faster than using jquery selector?